# Forgot password using ASP.Net membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider, forgot-password

Is it possible to implement a "forgot password" using ASP.Net membership provider?

Any sample link is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[PasswordRecovery](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/login/passwordrecovery.aspx)** control or You can call GetPassword() or ResetPassword() methods on your membership provider.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I've seen so far is to reset it as follows:

```
MemberShipUser user = MemberShip.GetUset("someUserName");
user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(), "new-password-word");
```

This is very handy especially if your passwords are hashed.

Comment: hi, the class name is case sensitive. the correct one is like this         MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("userName");
        user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(), "newPassword");   thanks your answer worked for me with change in case.

Comment: in order to change password we can also use    MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(userName);
                mu.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);